# Why are all of my tables being deleted when I shut down my Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm running a Spring Boot application on an EC2 instance. It seems to be connecting to the database just fine. However, when I shut it down (Ctrl+C), it deletes all of the tables in the database

> Hibernate: drop table if exists table1
> Hibernate: drop table if exists table2
> Hibernate: drop table if exists table3

This is something that I expect to happen at the beginning of instantiation. This is the way I have it set up in my `applications.properties`. But I don't want this to happen when shutting it down. I suspect there's something in my properties file that I need to change, but I'm not sure what exactly.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://my-database.cggorzw3flvw.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop #this is probably what's deleting my tables
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
server.port=8080
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing really AWS specific about your question. This is just about the behavior of Spring JPA and Hibernate. It should be behaving exactly the same if you ran the app on your local computer, instead of AWS. Also, you've already identified the Spring Boot configuration setting that is causing the problem and added a comment to that effect already.

Comment: That is what create drop does. http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-schema/#:~:text=create%2Ddrop%20%E2%80%93%20This%20option%20instructs,schema%20will%20be%20dropped%20again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the problem already: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` will create the schema on startup, deleting any data that is currently there, and delete the schema on shutdown. This is certainly not an appropriate setting for a production environment.

You could try changing that setting to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to only update the existing schema.

A more appropriate configuration for Spring Boot in a production environment is to use the integration with database migration tools Luquibase or Flyway.

Comment: I understand. I thought `create-drop` would only drop the table at the BEGINNING of the instance. I was terminating my spring instance in my localhost without properly shutting it down.

Comment: Why this does not have a vote up? :o

Answer (score 0):

create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped

I would advise you to use a high level migration tool (like flyway) as stated in [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

This would also be safer for production.